# Integer valued polynomials over several variables

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, conjectures

For simplicity this is about polynomials in just two variables.

Any $f\in\mathbb Q[X,Y]$ can be written as a linear combination of monomials 
$X^iY^j$ and therefore as a sum of polynomials $p_{ij}\in\mathbb Q[X^iY^j]$ over one variable:

$$\displaystyle f(X,Y)=p_{00}+\sum_{\gcd(i,j)=1}p_{ij}(X^iY^j).$$

> My question: is the subring of all integer valued polynomials $f$ over
>   two variables identical with the subring of all sums of integer valued
>   polynomials $p_{ij}$ over one variable as above?

An integer valued polynomial in one variable is a polynomial $p$ with rational coefficients such that $p(\mathbb Z)\subseteq \mathbb Z$. And corresponding for polynomials over several variables.

It might be some abuse of language to call $p_{ij}$ polynomials over one variable, they may rather be polynomials over one variable applied to monomials $X^iY^j$.

Comment: What about $x(x-1)y(y-1)/4$?

Comment: @Okay, thanks! It's a proper subring then.

Comment: The counterexample given above is the product of binomial coefficient polynomials $\binom{x}{2}\binom{y}{2}$.  Integer-valued polynomials in one variable $X$ are linear combinations of binomial coefficient polynomials $\binom{X}{i}$, so do you want to consider polynomials $p_{ij}(\binom{X}{i}\binom{Y}{j})$ instead?

Comment: @Lehs is it a subring?

Comment: @KConrad the polynomials ${x \choose i}{y\choose j}$ form a basis in the $\mathbb{Z}$-module of integer-valued polynomials in two variables. So you do not even need these $p_{ij}(\cdot)$, only integer coefficients.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: No, you are right. It's an awkward construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every polynomial function $f : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of the polynomials $\pmatrix{x \\ i} \pmatrix{y \\ j}$ with $i,j \geq 0$.

Indeed, let $f : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ be a polynomial function. By interpolation, we know that $f$ comes from a polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$. Since the polynomials $\pmatrix{x \\ n}$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, we may write $f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j \geq 0} a_{i,j} \pmatrix{x \\ i} \pmatrix{y \\ j}$ with $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Since $f(0,y) = \sum_{j \geq 0} a_{0,j} \pmatrix{y \\ j}$ is integer-valued, we have $a_{0,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$. Moreover, by the recursion formula for binomial coefficients
\begin{equation*}
f(x+1,y)-f(x,y)  = \sum_{i \geq 1, j \geq 0} a_{i,j} \pmatrix{x \\ i-1} \pmatrix{y \\ j}
\end{equation*}
so that $a_{1,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$, and an easy induction on $i$ gives $a_{i,j} \in \mathbb{Z}$ for every $i,j$.

The same proof works for polynomial functions $f : \mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$.