# Particular complex fractions

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

We known $\forall P\in \mathbb C(x)=\{\dfrac N D:(N, D) \in \mathbb C[x] \} $, if $P(\mathbb Z) \subset \mathbb Z$ then $P\in \mathbb Q[x] $.

> Is it true that $\forall P\in \mathbb C(x, y)=\{\dfrac N D:(N, D) \in \mathbb C[x, y] \} ,$
>
> if $P(\mathbb Z, \mathbb Z)=\{P(n,m) : (n,m)\in\mathbb Z^2\} \subset \mathbb Z$ then $ P\in \mathbb Q[x, y] $?

Comment: To make sense, you need more words, such as "if" and "then".

Comment: Yes, and something stronger is true, see the answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320323).

Comment: $\mathbb C(x, y) =\{\dfrac N D\text{ ; } (N, D) \in \mathbb C[x, y]^2\} $

Comment: What's $P(Z,Z)$? Is this $P(Z\times Z)$ or $\{ P(n,n): n\in Z\}$?

Comment: P(Z, Z) ={P(n, m) : (n, m) \in Z^2}

Comment: Is [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049(97)00120-5) of any use?

Answer (score 2):

This is well known, but I'll give a short proof using 3 dimensions as an example.

Every power $x^n$ can be written as the integer linear combination of binomial coefficients $\binom xj$ for $0\le j\le n$. So we can write our polynomial as a finite sum
$$p(x,y,z)=\sum_{i,j,k} a_{i,j,k} \binom xi\binom yj\binom zk.$$
Now consider the lexicographically least $(i,j,k)$ such that $x^iy^jz^k$ is present in $p$.  Then $p(i,j,k)=a_{i,j,k}$ so $a_{i,j,k}$ is an integer. Now subtract off $a_{i,j,k}\binom xi\binom yj\binom zk$ and repeat. Finally we have that all $a_{i,j,k}$ are integers.

Comment: $P\in \mathbb C(x, y) $ iff $\exists N, D\in \mathbb C[x, y], P= \dfrac N D$

Comment: Hence P is a fraction and not a polynomial.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were asking about polynomials. I'm not sure your notation is standard enough to not require definition.